# Disable dropdown list in file selector

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I have designed a uploader using HTML/CSS and Jquery as frontend and backend is in c#. I was wondering that is there any way to disable the dropdown list in this file selector which says "Custom Files" or is there a way so that no other option appears in this list except the extensions I allow?

[image: This is how it looks when a user clicks on select files]

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1):

Use `accept attribute` for `input type file`

```
<input type="file" name="my-image" id="image" accept="image/*" />
```

For specific extensions, you can use `,` to separate

```
<input type="file" name="my-image" id="image" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" />
```

**EDIT**

I believe it's completely out of scope from our programming, it is dependent on browser.

I would prefer to check file extension by validating it using programming.

```
$('#my_file_field').change(function(){
    var ext = $('#my_file_field').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
        alert('invalid extension!');
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess OP is already using `accept` attribute because he has `Custom Files` choice in dropdown list file dialog. BUT, i don't see any other way though

Comment: Thanks for your help. As A. Wolff told I am already using `accept` attribute. My question was that I do not want any other options in that dropdown list.

Comment: @ArnavDhiman I would suggest to provide the allowed extension in HTML input tag using accept and rest of things you can validate using `change`.